# How can I reshape a long dataset into a short data set with multiple variables

Tags: r, reshape

**UPDATE

My data set contains 314090 observations in the following format:

| UPDATEDID | BRIEF_ID | gamma | LDR_SUM | LDR_Topic | LDR_7Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 04999120040277 | 2.879744e-03 | 0.15326902 | supervises collective followers very closely | 1 |

Note: there are duplicate BRIEF_ID numbers (3205 unique #s), LDR_Topics (15 unique LDR topics with corresponding LDR_7Codes) so that is why the data is very long.

I'd like to reshape this data whereby each row is a unique #s (3205 rows) and each LDR_Topic (15) is it's own unique column (20 columns total) with its corresponding LDR_SUM as values within the column. For example:

| UPDATEDID | BRIEF_ID | supervises collective followers very closely |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 04999120040277 | 0.15326902 |

So far I've tried:

```
BriefingGammas4<-reshape(data = BriefingGammas3, 
                         idvar = c("UPDATEDID", "BRIEF_ID"),
                         timevar = "LDR_Topic", 
                         direction = "wide")
```

But it aborts into a new session.

Any advice? Thank you!

***** UPDATE

I tried the following approaches but neither resulted in the correct table.

```
install.packages("data.table")
library (data.table)
```

```
BriefingGammas7 <- as.data.table(BriefingGammas6)
BriefingGammas7 <- dcast(BriefingGammas7, UPDATEDID + BRIEF_ID ~ LDR_Topic, value.var = 'LDR_SUM')
```

This resulted in the correct 3205 rows, but the incorrect values for each LDR_Topic (they should not be identical, and should be decimals. These numbers seem to reflect LDR_7Code which is not in the dataset). See below for an example:

| UPDATEDID | BRIEF_ID | acquired resources | distributed resources | enhanced |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01999110036250 | 2 | 4 | 15 |
| 2 | 01999120041284 | 2 | 4 | 15 |
| 3 | 01999300213 | 2 | 4 | 15 |

I then tried this:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library (tidyverse)
```

```
BriefingGammas6 <- BriefingGammas5 |> 
 pivot_wider(names_from = LDR_Topic, values_from = LDR_SUM) |>
 select(-c(gamma, LDR_7Code))
```

This resulted in the correct values per LDR_Topic, but the incorrect number of rows. It stayed at 314,090 rows instead of 3205. See example:

| UPDATEDID | BRIEF_ID | acquired resources | distributed resources | enhanced |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01999110036250 | 0.02843241 | NA | NA |
| 2 | 01999110036250 | NA | 0.010892233 | NA |
| 3 | 01999110036250 | NA | 0.010892233 | 0.006081761 |
| 4 | 01999110036250 | 0.02843241 | NA | 0.006081761 |

Basically, it filled out the values for each topic for 3205 rows (duplicating it multiple times) and then started filling out the values for the next topic. But I'd like to get the 3205 rows to look like this:

| UPDATEDID | BRIEF_ID | acquired resources | distributed resources | enhanced |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01999110036250 | 0.02843241 | 0.010892233 | 0.006081761 |
| 2 | 01999120041284 | 0.1594207 | 0.005315201 | 0.004850703 |
| 3 | 01999300213 | 0.4374699 | 0.01607505 | 0.003971634 |

The last one I tried was this:

```
BriefingGammas7<-reshape(data = BriefingGammas6, 
                         idvar = c("UPDATEDID", "BRIEF_ID"),
                         timevar = "LDR_Topic",
                         v.names = "LDR_SUM",
                         direction = "wide")
```

Which resulted in this:

| UPDATEDID | BRIEF_ID | "acquired resources", "distributed"... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01999110036250 | NA |
| 2 | 01999120041284 | NA |

No other rows came out.

******************SOLUTION UPDATE*******************

Step 1. reduce number of variables
Step 2. Remove duplicate observations

```
BriefingGammas7 <- subset(BriefingGammas6, !duplicated(subset(BriefingGammas6, select=c(UPDATEDID, BRIEF_ID, LDR_SUM, LDR_Topic))))
```

Step 3. use tidy verse way in the comment below.

```
BriefingGammas8 <- BriefingGammas7 |> 
 pivot_wider(names_from = LDR_Topic, values_from = LDR_SUM)
```

Comment: First step is to delete the columns you are not interested in.  This will help with the memory issue, though you may still need to break up the problems into parts.  Are you expecting a dataframe 100+ columns wide?  Can you provide an example of the reduced data for 1 complete "Brief_ID"?  Use the output from the `dput()` function, it makes it easier to copy the information to reproduce.

Comment: @Dave2e Thank you for your feedback! I reduced the number of variables in my dataset and retried the previous code, which still didn't work. I haven't used dput() before but I'll give it a try and/or provide you another example for a complete set of the Brief_ID shortly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the case clearer, I tried to create a second row with dummy data that follows the pattern of data in the first row:

```
dput(dat)
structure(list(UPDATEDID = c(16, 17), BRIEF_ID = c("04999120040277", 
"14999120040277"), gamma = c(879.744, 779.744), LDR_SUM = c(0.15326902, 
0.25326902), LDR_Topic = c("supervises collective followers very closely", 
"does something else"), LDR_7Code = c(1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

dat
  UPDATEDID       BRIEF_ID   gamma  LDR_SUM                                    LDR_Topic LDR_7Code
1        16 04999120040277 879.744 0.153269 supervises collective followers very closely         1
2        17 14999120040277 779.744 0.253269                          does something else         2
```

### A base R way

```
dat |> 
  reshape(direction = "wide", 
          idvar  = "UPDATEDID",
          timevar ="LDR_Topic",
          v.names = "LDR_SUM")|>
  subset(select = -c(gamma, LDR_7Code))

# The result

#  UPDATEDID       BRIEF_ID LDR_SUM.supervises collective followers very closely LDR_SUM.does something else
#1        16 04999120040277                                             0.153269                          NA
#2        17 14999120040277                                                   NA                    0.253269
```

## A tidyverse way

```
library(tidyverse)

dat |> 
 pivot_wider(names_from = LDR_Topic, values_from = LDR_SUM) |>
 select(-c(gamma, LDR_7Code))

#The result

# A tibble: 2 × 4
#  UPDATEDID BRIEF_ID       `supervises collective followers very closely` `does something else`
#      <dbl> <chr>                                                   <dbl>                 <dbl>
#1        16 04999120040277                                          0.153                NA    
#2        17 14999120040277                                         NA                     0.253
```

### A data.table way (recommended for memory efficiency)

```
library(data.table)

dat.dt <- as.data.table(dat)
dcast(dat.dt, UPDATEDID + BRIEF_ID ~ LDR_Topic, value.var = 'LDR_SUM')

# The result

#   UPDATEDID       BRIEF_ID does something else supervises collective followers very closely
#1:        16 04999120040277                  NA                                     0.153269
#2:        17 14999120040277            0.253269                                           NA
```

### Updates

Based on your explanation, the `tidyverse` way basically works on the right direction. The only problem is the duplicated rows that have `NA`s in some of its columns and you want them to collapse into a single row. This is easy to do with `fill()` and `distinct()` functions. The only problem in your example is that the `UPDATEDID` changed from `1,2,3,4` to `1` with no explanation. Hence, for now, I assume that we can ignore the `UPDATEDID` (you can create a new column for it later) and we need only to consider `BRIEF_ID`.

```
yourdf <- structure(list(UPDATEDID = 1:4, BRIEF_ID = c(1999110036250, 1999110036250, 
1999110036250, 1999110036250), acquired_resources = c(0.02843241, 
NA, NA, 0.02843241), distributed_resources = c(NA, 0.010892233, 
0.010892233, NA), enhanced = c(NA, NA, 0.006081761, 0.006081761
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

yourdf   # I change the space to '_' to make it easier to control

  UPDATEDID    BRIEF_ID acquired_resources distributed_resources    enhanced
1         1 1.99911e+12         0.02843241                    NA          NA
2         2 1.99911e+12                 NA            0.01089223          NA
3         3 1.99911e+12                 NA            0.01089223 0.006081761
4         4 1.99911e+12         0.02843241                    NA 0.006081761

yourdf[,-1] |>
     fill(acquired_resources,distributed_resources,enhanced, 
     .direction = 'downup') |> 
     distinct()
    

# The result
     BRIEF_ID acquired_resources distributed_resources    enhanced
1 1.99911e+12         0.02843241            0.01089223 0.006081761
```

Then, the complete step would be:

```
dat |> 
 pivot_wider(names_from = LDR_Topic, values_from = LDR_SUM) |>
 select(-c(gamma, LDR_7Code)) |>
 fill(acquired_resources,distributed_resources,enhanced, 
     .direction = 'downup') |> 
     distinct()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this! I will give it a try later today as my computer froze earlier from the large dataset and needs to cool down. Will update you after!

Comment: I added `data.table` way in my updated answer to provide a solution that should be more memory-efficient.

Comment: Thank you for providing several different options to try! Unfortunately, none of them worked as hoped. (see edits above for results) Any advice? Thank you!!

Comment: Ah--I appreciate you so much! you got me close enough such that I was able to resolve the rest! basically, I removed all duplicate observations first. Then I used your tidyverse way which resulted in the desired table. I'll post the updated solution. Thanks again!!

Comment: Oh nice. But I've updated my answer before reading your comment. Please kindly have a  check on it.